# How to sort number that are in p/q formate using c++

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, fractions

**Given a positive integer  `n` , you have to print the sequence in ascending order which consisting of fractions between 0 to 1**

*Input- 6.

*Output-0/1 ,1/6 , 1/5 , 1/4 , 1/3 , 2/5 , 1/2 , 3/6 , 3/5 , 2/3 , 3/4 , 4/5, 5/6 , 1/1 .*

I have written code in c++ but it not giving correct output

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<algorithm>
#include<set>
using namespace std;

long gcd(long a, long b);

void foo(double input)
{    

     double frac = input ;
    const long precision = 1000000000; // This is the accuracy.

    long gcd_ = gcd(round(frac * precision), precision);

    long denominator = precision/gcd_;
    long numerator = round(frac * precision) / gcd_;
    cout << numerator << "/" << denominator <<",";
}

long gcd(long a, long b){

if (a == 0)
        return b;
    else if (b == 0)
        return a;

    if (a < b)
        return gcd(a, b % a);
    else
        return gcd(b, a % b);
}


int main()
{

    double n;
    set<double>s;
    int c=0;
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=n;j>0;j--)
        {
            if(i<j)
            {
            s.insert((double)i/j);
            }


        }
    }
    cout<<"0/1"<<",";
    while(!s.empty())
    {
        foo(*s.begin());
          s.erase(s.begin());
    }
    cout<<"1/1";
```

output- 0/1, 166666667/1000000000, 1/5, 1/4,333333333/1000000000, 2/5, 1/2, 3/5, 666666667/1000000000, 3/4, 4/5,833333333/1000000000,1/1

Comment: What output *do* you get? And have you used a debugger to step through the code and try to find out if it works as you expects?

Comment: I am getting  output- 0/1,166666667/1000000000,1/5,1/4,333333333/1000000000,2/5,1/2,3/5,666666667/1000000000,3/4,4/5,833333333/1000000000,1/1 Here input is=6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a bad idea try to recalculate numerator and denominator when you can simply memorize they.

If you, instead of a `std::set<double>`, use a `std::map<double, std::pair<int, int>>`, you can use the key (a `double`) to sort the fractions and the value (a `std::pair<int, int>`) to print they.

So `foo()` can receive numerator and denominator.

The following is a full example

```
#include<map>
#include<iostream>

constexpr long gcd (long a, long b)
 { return (a == 0) ? b
                   : (b == 0) ? a
                              : (a < b) ? gcd(a, b % a)
                                        : gcd(b, a % b); }

void foo (long num, long den)
 {    
   long const g { gcd(num, den) };

   std::cout << (num / g) << '/' << (den / g) << ", ";
 }

int main ()
 {
   int n;

   std::map<double, std::pair<int, int>> m;

   std::cin >> n;

   for ( auto i = 0 ; i < n ; ++i )
    {
      for ( auto j = n ; j > i ; --j )
            m.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                      std::forward_as_tuple(double(i)/j),
                      std::forward_as_tuple(i, j));
    }

   for ( auto const e : m )
      foo( e.second.first, e.second.second );

   std::cout << "1/1" << std::endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the wrong way to go about it.

You should try to make a fraction class which stores the numerator and denominator and works with them directly.

Something like this should work:

```
struct fraction {
  int numerator, denominator;
  bool operator<(const fraction& f) const {
    return numerator*f.denominator < f.numerator*denominator;
  }
}
```

This is just the bare thing and should work for the kind of input that you have, but you might need to specialise it (negative numbers, large numerator and denominator, dealing with different representations of the same fraction…)